# problema con StringWriter y &

Tags: c#, string, xml, utf-8

Tengo el siguiente código para convertir un XML en una cadena concatenada de texto para la facturación electrónica, todo va bien excepto cuando en los datos del xml contienen un & por que en el resultado me devuelve el `&` como `&amp;` (`P&G0101010X0` retorna `P&amp;G0101010X0`).

¿Cómo puedo evitar esa conversión?

```
public string ObtenCadena(string FileXML)  {
            //Cargo el XML
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FileXML);
            XPathDocument myXPathDoc = new XPathDocument(reader);

            //Cargo el XSLT
            XslCompiledTransform myXslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();
            myXslTrans.Load(FileXSLT);

            StringWriter str = new StringWriter();
            
            XmlTextWriter myWriter = new XmlTextWriter(str);
            
            //Aplicando transformacion
            myXslTrans.Transform(myXPathDoc, null, myWriter);

            //Resultado
            string  vrCadena = str.ToString();
            return vrCadena;
        }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Y si usas la funcion replace?

Comment: No debe ser `StringWriter` si no `Transform` el que te lo está modificando. Creo que el problema esta en tu xslt, dado que `&`  es un caracter especial

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de contenido quieres crear con XSLT, es XML o HTML o solamente texto? Como en XML o en HTML un ampersand `&` se debe escribir como `&amp;`, `XslCompiledTransform` ha producido el formato correcto si has declarado `xsl:output method="xml"` o `xsl:output method="html"` en tu XSLT. Se puede declarar `xsl:output method="text"`, en este caso XslCompiledTransform va a producir `&`, pero creo que solamente si lo dejas escribir diractamente a un TextWriter, por ejemplo `myXslTrans.Transform(myXPathDoc, null, str)`, no si utilizas un `XmlTextWriter` encima del StringWriter.

Comment: @MartinHonnen revise el xsl y si esta configurado como "text"    `<xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>`    (quiero crear solamente texto)  hare la prueba enviando directamente al StringWriter, gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como bien lo comento @MartinHonnen, el `XMLTextWriter` estaba de mas, al pasar la transformacion directamente al `StringWriter` el problema se soluciona, gracias a todos

```
StringWriter str = new StringWriter();
            
//Esta linea ya no se necesita
//XmlTextWriter myWriter = new XmlTextWriter(str);
            
//Aplicando transformacion
myXslTrans.Transform(myXPathDoc, null, str);
```

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo, ni de modificar el título de tu pregunta, para que otras personas con el mismo problema puedan llegar con facilidad a la misma.